# Float to time with hundredth of a second - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, time

I want to pass a time to Apple's leaderboard for my app. The time is in a float format like 9.23 (9 seconds, 23 hundredths)

How can i convert this float to NSDate and pass in with the following code:

```
[self.gameCenterManager reportScore: self.currentScore forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
```

Comment: `@(9.23)` box and pass. Do you want to replace `self.currentScore` with 9.23 ?

Comment: well, the 9.23 has to be in time format because gamecenter isnt getting right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `NSDate` from `float` or `double` by:

```
double score=9.23;//or anythign in float or double
NSDate *date=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:score];
```

then you can use:

```
[self.gameCenterManager reportScore:date forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
```

Comment: thanks! The problem i am facing right now is that gamecenter needs a int64_t format....

Comment: @AndrewHo: now you need to convert it into int64_t format. Actually you didn't mention what is your target api, what type it require, we we all can guess only.